# question on java nodes load balancing here or webapps

Tags: support

[tune web server backend - custom load balance by customer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42973/tune-web-server-backend-custom-load-balance-by-customer) belongs here?

was not sure when i posted but now i see the tags i wanted are not there but are here !

question to tune back end - where the requests from web servers go to -> java nodes. hit them evenly or send of one customer only to few nodes for better optimizations and memory.

Comment: It is completely off-topic for webapps.  It is kinda on-topic here, but the way it is currently written would almost certainly get it closed as Not Constructive, or Not a real question.  Your question simply does not provide enough meaningful context for people to provide a useful answer.  It is not asked in a way to get people to provide a good generic answer.

Comment: Question disappeared now and i did not make a copy :( is there a way to get the text back so i can edit and post it in server fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is on topic for Server Fault, but in its present form it would almost instantly be closed as a duplicate of [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](https://serverfault.com/q/350454/126632).

Before you move the question here, I would suggest heavily editing it to focus on the specific technical issues of concern.

Answer (score 3):

I'm really not sure what you're asking. If it's related to scalability design, the inner workings of your application will determine that. The question would not be appropriate for Server Fault as we don't handle application design patterns. Am I misunderstanding the Question?